# Why is my view not running through hook_views_pre_render or theme_preprocess_views_view?

Tags: views, hooks, theming

I am trying to modify a view before its rendered. I have a page with two view blocks on it. I have the following code in my template.php:

```
function isn3_preprocess_views_view (&$vars) {
  drupal_set_message('Hey', 'status');
  dpm($vars);
}

function isn3_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  drupal_set_message('Ho', 'status');
  dpm($view);
}
```

However when I visit the page, each function only gets called once, despite there being two views on the page. Is there any reason that a view wouldn't run through either of those functions?

Comment: Is that the code of a theme, or a module?

Comment: That code is running in the tempalte.php of the theme, named 'isn3' however I have also added the hook_views_pre_render() to a module and get the same issue. Odd thing is that I cleared the cache, then reloaded, and I saw all three function being hit by both views, but when I reloaded again, it just shows one. Could this be some sort of caching issue?

Comment: which version you are using?